# Prove that $\Bigl\{\frac{S_n}{n},n\geq 1 \Bigr\}$ is a Markov chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Let $\{X_n , n\geq 1\}$ be a sequence of random variables that have the same uniform distribution on $[0,2]$ and let $S_n=\sum_{k=0}^nX_k$.
 
$\mathbf a)$ Prove that $\left\{\frac{S_n}{n},n\geq 1 \right\}$ is a Markov chain.
$\mathbf b)$ Is $\left\{\Bigl[\frac{S_n}{n}\Bigr],n\geq 1 \right\}$ a Markov chain?
**Definition:** The random process $\{X_t, t\in T\}$ is called a Markov process if for any $n\geq3$, any $t_1<t_2<...<t_n\in T$ and any $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ from the set of all possible values, the following equality holds
$\operatorname{Pr}(X_{t_{n+1}}<x_{n+1}\mid X_{t_{n}}=x_n,\ldots,X_{t_1}=x_1)=\operatorname{Pr}(X_{t_{n+1}}<x_{n+1}\mid X_{t_n}=x_n)$. 
We are looking at it at discrete time points so it is a Markov chain.
I'm not given whether or not $X_n$ are independent of each other. We know the pdf and cdf of $X_n$ $$f{_X{_n}}(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{2}, & x\in[0,2] \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$ $$F{_X{_n}}(x)=\begin{cases} 0, & x <0 \\
x/2,  & 0, \leq x \leq 2 \\
1 & x > 2
\end{cases}$$ 
I don't know how to start or what to use. I'm aware that $\frac{S_n}{n}=\overline{X_n}$ and I know that $E[\overline{X_n}]=E[X_n]$. I wanted to find the pdf of $\overline{X_n}$ using characteristic functions but I can't use that neat property for sum of random variables because I don't know if they are independent.

Comment: I can only help to simplify the form. Define $T_{n}=\frac{S_n}{n}$. You need to show that $T_{n}$ is Markov. Note that $T_{n+1}=\frac{S_{n+1}}{n+1}=\frac{S_{n}+X_{n+1}}{n+1}= T_{n}\frac{n}{n+1}+\frac{X_{n+1}}{n+1}$.

Comment: If the $X_n$ are not independent I am not sure that  $\{S_n/n\}$ is a Markov chain.